# How make a spesific Java TreeNode

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to create a structure with:

```
Class Message
{private String text;
   ...
}
Class Folder
{....
}
```

A folder can contain several messages and other sub folder

Question:

how I can make this structure?

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly easy to just use a couple collections

```
Class Message {
  private String text;
  . . .
}

Class Folder {
  Collection<Message> messages;
  Collection<Folder> subFolders;
}
```

Collections can be instantiated as a number of classes, depending on what's appropriate